# Keep seeing this bug in our house

Tags: bug-identification

We keep seeing this bug in our house. Finally put a dead one in a bottle and took a closeup picture. The actual size is about 0.25 inch (6mm) long. Does anyone know what it might be?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. A few more details would be handy and a clear picture of the insect from the side. As it is we can tell that it is an insect (right number of legs probably). Where in the world are you? What behaviours does it have (climbs, flies, jumps etc.)?, What time of day do you see it?

Comment: Looks like some kind of mite

Comment: @Darren - no, mites do not have segmented body parts - they are all oval or circular, not elongated like this one. In addition the legs are generally uniform in shape, not larger at the top like these ones.

Comment: Looks similar to a flea to me. Adult flea colors vary from brown to red because they have been feeding.